# Saving function evaluations while using std::min_element()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Suppose you are given a vector of 2D points and are expected to find the point with the least [Euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm).

The points are provided as `std::vector<point_t> points` whith the following `typedef std::pair<double, double> point_t`. The norm can be calculated using

```
double norm(point_t p)
{
    return pow(p.first, 2) + pow(p.second, 2);
}
```

Writing the loop myself I would do the following:

```
auto leastPoint = points.cend();
auto leastNorm = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
for (auto iter = points.cbegin(), end = points.cend(); iter != end; ++iter)
{
    double const currentNorm = norm(*iter);
    if (currentNorm < leastNorm)
    {
        leastNorm = currentNorm;
        leastPoint = iter;
    }
}
```

But one should use STL algorithms instead of wirting one's own loops, so I'm tempted to to the following:

```
auto const leastPoint = std::min_element(points.cbegin(), points.cend(),
    [](point_t const lhs, point_t const rhs){ return norm(lhs) < norm(rhs); });
```

But there is a caveat: if `n = points.size()` then the first implementation needs `n` evaluations of `norm()`, but the second implementation needs `2n-2` evaluations. (at least if [this possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) is used)

So my question is if there exists any STL algorithm with which I can find that point but with only `n` evaluations of `norm()`?

**Notes:**

- I am aware that big-Oh complexity is the same, but still the latter will lead to twice as many evaluations
- Creating a separate vector and populating it with the distances seems a bit overkill just to enable the usage of an STL algorithm - different opinions on that?
- edit: I actually need an iterator to that vector element to erase that point.

Comment: there exists a similar library function which is used to accumulate results - accumulate a struct storing the point and buffering its norm and done ;)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, see NetVipeC's answer for the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of problem that [boost::transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) from the [boost iterator library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) is designed to solve. There are limitations with the decorated iterator approach however and the C++ standards committee [Ranges working group](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee) is looking into adding ranges to the standard which would potentially allow for a more functional approach of piping e.g. a transform to a min_element without needing temporary storage.

Eric Niebler has some interesting posts on ranges at his [blog](http://ericniebler.com/category/ranges/).

Unfortunately transform_iterator doesn't quite solve your problem given the way min_element is typically implemented - both iterators are dereferenced for each comparison so your function will still end up getting called more often than necessary. You could use the boost iterator_adaptor to implement something like a 'caching_transform_iterator' which avoids recomputing on each dereference but it would probably be overkill for something like norm(). It might be a useful technique if you had a more expensive computation though.

Comment: I don't understand how this saves one evaluation.
`std::min_element` will dereference two iterators per comparison which will involve two calls to `norm()` via boost::transform_iterator. (still very handy tool, thanks for showing me)
(sadly I can't reach the blog atm)

Comment: Looking at the implementation of min_element in my standard library  this is true. It *could* be implemented so as to only dereference each iterator once but it's not in the MSVC implementation apparently.

Comment: Another option would be to use the boost iterator_adaptor to implement a 'caching_transform_iterator' which saves the result of the computation. Questionable how worthwhile that really is though...

Comment: That is a nice apporach. It seems too much for my use case, but it might help others. If you add this information (no code needed) to your answer I will accept it. (and +1)

Comment: Updated my answer with the info from the commments.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::accumulate` (in the `algorithm` header):

Accumulate receive:

- `range`
- `initial value`
- `binary operator` (optional, if not passed, `operator+` would be called)

The `initial value` and every element of the `range` would be feed into the `operator`, the operator would return a result of the type of the `initial value` that would be feed into the next call to `operator` with the next element of the range and so on.

Example Code (Tested GCC 4.9.0 with C++11):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

typedef std::pair<double, double> point_t;

struct norm_t {
    point_t p;
    double norm;
};

double norm(const point_t& p) {
    return std::pow(p.first, 2) + std::pow(p.second, 2);
}

norm_t min_norm(const norm_t& x, const point_t& y) {
    double ny = norm(y);
    if (ny < x.norm)
        return {y, ny};
    return x;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<point_t> v{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

    norm_t first_norm{v[0], norm(v[0])};
    auto min_norm_point =
        std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), first_norm, min_norm);

    std::cout << "(" << min_norm_point.p.first << "," << min_norm_point.p.second
              << "): " << min_norm_point.norm << '\n';
}
```

You could cache the **minimum norm** in the `functor` for avoid extra calculation (be aware: I'm using info about the implementation of [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)). The second element is the **smallest found** and the first is the iteration element.

```
struct minimum_norm {
    minimum_norm() : cached_norm(-1) {}
    bool operator()(const point_t& first, const point_t& second) {
        if (cached_norm == -1)
            cached_norm = norm(second);
        double norm_first = norm(first);
        if (norm_first < cached_norm) {
            cached_norm = norm_first;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    double cached_norm;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<point_t> v{{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 2}, {7, 8}, {9, 10}};

    auto result = std::min_element(std::begin(v), std::end(v), minimum_norm());
    std::cout << "min element at: " << std::distance(std::begin(v), result) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But what if you want an iterator to the point, not just the value of the point?

Comment: Very interesting approach, albeit it lacks a bit clarity of code which a seemingly non-existent dedicated method (e.g., `std::min_element_eval()`) would have.
The thing is that I actually need the iterator as @aschepler mentioned to erase that element in the next step. (I will add this to the question)

Comment: The only idea for the iterator until now is search the point in the container with `std::find` after the `std::accumulate`. The other option is improve the hand made code (if you could use C++11 more improve is achievable)

Comment: I'm stuck with VC10, so some C++11 features are supported, others aren't. (range-based for-loops for example are not)
But I'm open to further suggestions and will see what is possible. (no need to mention how to avoid the first comparison, that's straight forward from the possible implementation of `std::min_element()`)

Comment: The new approach added might help you.

Comment: That is an idea that I also already had. But I don't like it at all, mainly because (as you mentioned) there is no guarantee by the STL that this order is enforced. Even if my current STL implementation does this it could change in the future.
For this (and other reasons) Sutter & Alexandrescu suggest in item 87 of their [C++ coding standards](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm) to only use pure functions as predicates, i.e., not using member or global state in predicates.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind this, I misread the question.

I think you are mistaken in your assumption that min_element will perform 2N-2 comparisons

[Per the c++ reference of min_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) you can see that the algorithm performs essentially N comparison, which is the minimum for an unsorted array.

Here is a copy for the (very) unlikely case that www.cplusplus.com ever fails.

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  ForwardIterator min_element ( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
  if (first==last) return last;
  ForwardIterator smallest = first;

  while (++first!=last)
    if (*first<*smallest)    // or: if (comp(*first,*smallest)) for version (2)
      smallest=first;
  return smallest;
}
```

Comment: There is not the correct overload, you need the one that receive the functor.

Comment: It's the number of function calls the problem, not the number of comparisons

Comment: I'm aware that both approaches need N comparisons, but as @6502 already said the number of evaluations of `norm()` is what makes the difference.