# Find minimum element based on a transformed value

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector` of geometry vectors that I want to find the vector with the minimum norm. I can do it with `std::minimum_element` but that results in twice as many norm calculations as what are actually needed. Very similar to these questions:

[Finding minimum element based on a transformed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175026/finding-minimum-element-based-on-a-transformed-value)

[Saving function evaluations while using std::min_element()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873070/saving-function-evaluations-while-using-stdmin-element)

Neither of which have a satisfactory answer. Using the possible implementations for [`std::minimum_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for inspiration I came up with:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryOperation, class XformT = double>
ForwardIt min_transformed_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
    if (first == last) return last;

    ForwardIt smallest = first;
    XformT smallest_val = unary_op(*first);

    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        XformT first_val = unary_op(*first);
        if (first_val < smallest_val) {
            smallest = first;
            smallest_val = first_val;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

which works fantastic. The only thing I don't like is how the type for `XformT` is specified. The compiler can't deduce it, so as a hack, I gave it the default type. Is there a better way to have it specified or deduced?

Example of it running is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Mvr69yFIMtxQB7yy

Comment: With regards to XformT, I think you could use `auto`?

Comment: Yes! I was way over thinking it. Make that into answer!

Comment: Great that it works! I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `auto`:

```cpp
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryOperation>
ForwardIt min_transformed_element(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
    if (first == last) return last;

    ForwardIt smallest = first;
    auto smallest_val = unary_op(*first);

    ++first;
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        auto first_val = unary_op(*first);
        if (first_val < smallest_val) {
            smallest = first;
            smallest_val = first_val;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```